# how to store elements in array after validation with regular expression in php

Tags: php, arrays, regex

I have a form in which will be  inserted text with the web addresses. And i already have regular expression validation rule t search for web address. This rule will replace web links to another text. But my task is to write a function for saving all of this addresses to array. How can i save all of this addresses to array?

This is my code that i have for now:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Expressions: Find web address in text</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php

    /*--------Functions---------*/
    function webCheck($webtext){
        global $web_check;
        $web_check = "/((http:\/\/www\.)|(http:\/\/)|(www\.))([a-z0-9]+([a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]+)*\.)+[a-z]+/i";
            return preg_replace($web_check, "<b>was weblink here</b>", $webtext);
        }

    /*--------End of Functions----------*/



    if(isset($_POST["webadd"])){
        $webtext = $_POST["webtext"]; 

        if (!empty($webtext)){
            echo webCheck($webtext);
        }else{
            echo "Feald cannot be empty. Please enter some text.";
        }

    }  else {
        echo "Please enter text in text area.";
    }
    ?>

    <form action="expression3.php" method="POST">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Find web address in text</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td> <textarea name="webtext" cols="50" rows="10"></textarea></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="submit" name="webadd" value="Find Web Address!" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store anything into an array by just using the [push](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php) function like so:

```
$my_links_array = array();
array_push($my_links_array, webCheck($webtext));
```

or through:

```
$array[] = webCheck($webtext);
```

which is practically the same for you but considered a lot faster

Answer (score 0):

You can use preg_replace_callback that allows to execute code in a closure:

```
$myarr = array();
return preg_replace_callback($web_check, 
                             function ($m) use (&$myarr) {
                                 $myarr[] = $m[0];
                                 return '<b>was weblink here</b>';
                             }, $webtext);
```

Note that to change a variable inside the closure, you need to pass it by reference.

Answer (score 0):

Try..

```
/*--------Functions---------*/
$arrWebAddreses = array();
function webCheck($webtext){
    global $web_check;
    $web_check = "/((http:\/\/www\.)|(http:\/\/)|(www\.))([a-z0-9]+([a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]+)*\.)+[a-z]+/i";
    $matches = array();
    preg_match($web_check, $webtext, $matches);

    if(count($matches)>0)
      $arrWebAdresses += $matches[0];        

    return preg_replace($web_check, "<b>was weblink here</b>", $webtext);
}

/*--------End of Functions----------*/
```